# Unable to make Multiselect display data properly in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem by which I'm unable to make [Vue-Multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) display what I want properly.

**Current Behaviour:**
[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
           <multiselect
          v-model="displayCategories"
          :selected="displayCategories"
          :options="optionsForSubCat"                   
          :searchable="false"
          :allow-empty="true"
          deselect-label="Can't remove this value"                  
          label="subCategories"    
          track-by="subCategories"
          >
          </multiselect>
```

**This is my json object to display the Type of Sub-Category:**

```
  "displayCategories": {
    "categoryId": "3080854a-13d9-4e38-ab96-358aa6405a2c",
    "categoryName": "Furniture",
    "subCategories": [
      {
        "subCategoryName": "Sofa",
        "subCategoryId": "21eb061d-9c67-4c55-ac48-e33e684a307c",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-24T13:07:18.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-24T13:08:28.000Z",
        "fk_categoryId": "3080854a-13d9-4e38-ab96-358aa6405a2c"
      },
      {
        "subCategoryName": "Bed",
        "subCategoryId": "2af11eee-5fce-4d97-b483-00a02de123ca",
        "createdAt": "2017-07-24T13:06:04.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2017-07-24T13:08:28.000Z",
        "fk_categoryId": "3080854a-13d9-4e38-ab96-358aa6405a2c"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Even if i changed the label and track-by to "subCategoryName", it does not even show the dropdown at all.

The **expected behaviour** would be Multiselect would show "Sofa", "Bed" in the dropdown.

How do i go about achieving the expected behaviour?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is `multiselect`?

Comment: @BertEvans Hi, sorry i forgot to put the link. I've just updated the question. This is [Vue-Multiselect](http://monterail.github.io/vue-multiselect/) , something like a dropdown list.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Im having a similar issue.